# Installing wiring between meter panel and main load center panel

Tags: service

If inside a wood framed wall, new construction w/drywall on one side and siding on the other, can I use separate wires, 2/0 in my case, or am I required to use a jacketed cable with two hots and a neutral?

Comment: I think either cable or conduit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use *cable* inside the wall. You can use *conduit* and run invididual wires *in* the conduit.

You **cannot** use individual wires without grouping and protecting them in conduit. Here, or anywhere outside of a junction box or (electrical) gutter/raceway.

This, specifically, is a part of the system where damage to the insulation can be particularly catastrophic, as it's all but unfused so the energy in an arc involving these wires is huge.

[Even if you are in a NEC2020 or later area enforcing the outside disconnect, a 200A arc is nothing to sneeze at. When the only upstream protection is a pole breaker somewhere, the possible current is considerably greater...] If there is an outside disconnect, you may need a 4th wire or metallic conduit for a ground separate from neutral. If it's just a meter can with no breaker, no separate ground is required.